# Organizar datos por letra referente en palabra con srtpos

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Amigos buenas tarde o días.

Estoy tratando de organizar unos datos dependiendo el código de referencia entendiendo que cada uno trae un código de fabricante, Digamos X, Y o Z y en el código trae AX201 o AY301 o AZ303 todo los codigos que lleven la X deben ir agrupados en parte de la tabla generada, de igual forma para Y, y para Z.

Lo estoy realizando con strpos pero no se porque no se agrupan bien o aveces se duplican:

Esté es mi código. Los datos se traen desde Woocommerce y una base de datos. Entonces sería difícil adjuntarlos con un JOIN, otra cuestión que estoy pensando es que si esto no resulta. Hacer el SRTPOS en el INSERT para que si tiene alguna de las makilas X Y O Z se almacene con está referencia. Agradezco su apoyo y quedo atento a si sería mejor darle una organización en el mismo insert basandonos en la referencia enviada por AJAX.

```
 if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $SQLtraedatos)) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
 $ProductoURL=$row[0];
 $idProducto=$row[1];
 $Peso=$row[2];
 $Referencia=$row[3];
 $FechaRealiza=$row[4];
 $idPedido=$row[5];
 $Observacioneslist=$row[6];
 $Cantidadlist=$row[7];
 $Precio=$row[8];
 
 $SQLTraeMk="SELECT Nombre FROM Makila";
 if ($resultMK = mysqli_query($con, $SQLTraeMk)) {  
 while ($rowMK = mysqli_fetch_row($resultMK)){
   $NMK=$rowMK[0];
 if(strpos($Referencia, $NMK) == true){
     if(empty($Precio)){
     $Precio=$PrecioGe;
 }
 $word="decolombiajoyas.com";
 if(strpos($ProductoURL, $word) !== false){ 
    $table.="<tr align='center'><td>$Referencia</td><td><img src='$ProductoURL' style='width: 
 100%; min-width: 200px; min-height: 200px; height: auto;'>";
 }
 else {
    $table.="<tr align='center'><td>$Referencia</td><td><img 
 src='https://pm.decolombiajoyas.com/PorMayor/files/".$ProductoURL."' style='width: 100%; min- 
 width: 200px; min-height: 200px; height: auto;'>";
 }
 $table.="</td><td>";
 if($Peso==0){
     $table.="Precio Por Pieza";
 }
 else { $table.="$Peso grs";}
 $table.="</td><td>";
 $j=0;
 
 $SQLTraeTallas="SELECT Medidas_has_Pedido.Cantidad, Medidas.Nombre FROM Pedido INNER JOIN 
 Medidas_has_Pedido ON Pedido.idPedido = Medidas_has_Pedido.Pedido_idPedido INNER JOIN Medidas 
 ON 
 Medidas_has_Pedido.Medidas_idMedidas = Medidas.idMedidas where Pedido.idPedido=".$idPedido." 
 ORDER BY Medidas.Nombre ASC";
  //var_dump($SQLTraeTallas);

 if($Cantidadlist==0){
 if ($resultaM = mysqli_query($con, $SQLTraeTallas)) {
 while ($rowMe = mysqli_fetch_row($resultaM)){
     
     if ($rowMe[0]!=0){
     $table.= "T: ".$rowMe[1]." = ".$rowMe[0]."<br>";}
     $SumatoriaCantidad[$idPedido]+=$rowMe[0];
 }
 
 }
 if(empty($Peso)){
  $table.= "Total Cantidad : ".$SumatoriaCantidad[$idPedido];
 $Total=$SumatoriaCantidad[$idPedido]*$Precio;
 $PesoU=0;
  }
  else{
  $table.= "Total Cantidad : ".$SumatoriaCantidad[$idPedido];
 $Total=$SumatoriaCantidad[$idPedido]*$Peso*$Precio;
 $PesoU=$SumatoriaCantidad[$idPedido]*$Peso;}
 }
  else {
    
    $table.= "$Cantidadlist U";
    $PesoU=$Cantidadlist*$Peso;
    if (empty($Peso)){
    $Total=$Cantidadlist*$Precio;
    }
    else {
    $Total=$Cantidadlist*$Peso*$Precio;}
    } 
 
 $TotalEstimadoG+=$Total;
 $TotalEstimado=number_format(
 $TotalEstimadoG,
 0, // number of decimal places
  ',', // character to use as decimal point
  '.' // character to use as thousands separator
 );
 $TotalPeso+=$PesoU;
 //var_dump($Precio);
 $table.="</td><td>";
 if($Peso==0){
     $table.="Precio Por Pieza";
 }
 else { $table.="$PesoU grs";}
 $table.="</td><td>$".$Precio."</td><td>$".$Total."</td><td>$Observacioneslist</td></tr>";
 }
  }}
  }
 }
 $table.="</table></div><br><br><h1 align='center'>Tu Pedido Ha Sido Finalizado</h1><h3 
 align='center'>Precio estimado del Pedido : $ ".$TotalEstimado."</h3>";
 
 $table.="<h3 align='center'>Peso estimado del pedido : ".$TotalPeso." grs .</h3><br><br> 
 <br>";
 


 
  
  
 echo $table;
```

Comment: `strpos` no es para ese propósito... esto puede venir directamente ordenado desde la query mysql usando `ORDER BY Columna ASC`

Comment: tambien hay un problema ... no has enviado ningún ejemplo de tu estructura de tu base de datos ... y tampoco de que es lo que esperas...

Comment: No veo razón para no conseguirlo en una sola consulta, al menos con la información que proporcionas; pareciera que obvias de mas.

Comment: Lo solucione con el srtpos insertando la Makila que trae desde la Referencia y luego o llame  con el Order by. Gracias!